# undefined method on ActiveRecord::Relation object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

the following code

```
fieldvalue = Admin::FieldValue.where(:item_id => @admin_item.id, :field_id => key)
fieldvalue.update_attributes(:value => value)
```

raise the following error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `update_attributes' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000102dfc868>):
```

why is it a `Relation` object and not a `FieldValue` object, what's the right way to manage this

Comment: you can `update_attributes` only for exact AR object,or you should use `update_all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fieldvalue` should return only one value?

```
fieldvalue = Admin::FieldValue.where(:item_id => @admin_item.id, :field_id => key).first
fieldvalue.update_attributes(:value => value)
```

Or if you expect multiple items:

```
fieldvalue = Admin::FieldValue.where(:item_id => @admin_item.id, :field_id => key)
fieldvalue.update_all(:value => value)
```

Comment: yes Admin::FieldValue.where(:item_id => @admin_item.id, :field_id => key) should returns only one value

Comment: ok I missed the .first thx!!! (more explanation could be found at http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface)